# Templating engine that binds model attributes to view?

Tags: templates, backbone.js, model-binding

When rendering a template through a Backbone view you will often end up with some code that looks something like this:

```
ShirtView = {
  template: JST["/templates/shirt_template"],
  el: ".shirt-element"

  render: function() {
    var html = this.template({color: this.model.color, size: this.model.size});
    this.$el.html(html);
  }
}
```

This is all well and good and your template will render with the attributes you wanted. But if `this.model.color` changes then it will not be reflected in the view. You can then use something like modelbinder to explicitly bind elements in the view to your model, but this means introducing extra code to your view.

What I am wondering is if there are any templating engines, like Moustache or Handlebars, that automatically updates the elements belonging to the fields in the attributes object as the model changes, without me having to specify it in the view?

Comment: do you mean something like this http://nytimes.github.com/backbone.stickit/ ?

Comment: Backbone intentionally excludes that as many apps don't need that functionality. So, you'd need to add it. ModelBinder is one decent option. Another is stickit as suggested. But, there are certainly free frameworks like AngularJS and KnockoutJS that have it baked in. However, they aren't intended to be used with Backbone. The template engines would need to understand how to track changes to the data, so it's not something that is just plug-n-play, as Backbone has it's own techniques for triggering change notifications for example.

Comment: If you like Knockoutjs, you can combine their powers using Knockback. http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback/

Comment: StickIt seems very nice but it is basically the same as modelBinder. What I would like a templating engine much like Handlebars that sets up a layer between the template and the model that listens to model:change events and updates any affected elements automatically.

Comment: Simon, that's what stickit does - binds model attributes and view elements, so any change on either end will get synchronized to the other.

Comment: @user2095627 - indeed, and I think it seems like a super library, but what I am asking for is if there is a templating engine that does the same thing. StickIt still requires you to add a bindings object to your view and explicitly call ```stickit()```. These are minimal things of course, but I am wondering if there are any templating engines that take care of these things for you implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have suggested, there are several libraries you can use for this ... but I'd like to suggest that you don't need to.  I work on a Backbone-powered site with thousands (heck, probably tens or hundreds of thousands) of lines of code, and all we use is our own custom base class.

In essence, all you need to do is:

```
var TemplatedView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        this.renderTemplate();
    }.
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});
```

then you can make any new view a templated one with just:

```
var ShirtView = TemplatedView.extend({
    template: JST["/templates/shirt_template"],
    el: ".shirt-element"
});
```

or, if you have some custom render logic, you just need to call `renderTemplate`:

```
var AdvancedShirtView = TemplatedView.extend({
    template: JST["/templates/shirt_template"],
    el: ".shirt-element",

    render: function() {
        this.model.fold();
        this.renderTemplate();
        this.model.press();
    }
});
```

Now we have a few enhancements beyond that (eg. if someone specifies a "rawTemplate" property on one of our views, our `renderTemplate` will compile it in to a proper template), but that's the beauty of rolling your own solution for something like this: you get exactly what you want.

Or you can use a library :-)  But personally, for something that's both so simple and so integral to your site, I don't see why you'd want to.